# Camera preview still black

Tags: android, android-camera

I'm trying the camera preview on my Android applications. When I try on my real devices, it gives me black screen.

This is my code and it doesn't throw any error, but the screen is still black. Any ideas?

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.PixelFormat;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.hardware.Camera.Parameters;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;

public class ARrazerNav extends Activity{

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    try{
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        CustomCameraView cv = new CustomCameraView(this.getApplicationContext());
        FrameLayout r1 = new FrameLayout(this.getApplicationContext());
        setContentView(r1);
        r1.addView(r1);
    }catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }
}

public class CustomCameraView extends SurfaceView{
    Camera camera;
    SurfaceHolder previewHolder;
    public CustomCameraView(Context ctx){
        super(ctx);
        previewHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
        previewHolder.addCallback(surfaceHolderListener);
    }
    SurfaceHolder.Callback surfaceHolderListener = new SurfaceHolder.Callback(){

        public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            camera.stopPreview();
            camera.release();
        }

        public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            camera = Camera.open();
            try{
                camera.setPreviewDisplay(previewHolder);
            }catch (Throwable th) {
                // TODO: handle exception
            }
        }

        public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,
                int height) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Parameters params = camera.getParameters();
            params.setPreviewSize(width, height);
            params.setPictureFormat(PixelFormat.JPEG);
            camera.setParameters(params);
            camera.startPreview();

        }
    };
}

}
```

Can somebody give me some sort of explanation why it gives me black screen?

Comment: In my case; for reference The Manifest.permission.WRITE_MEDIA_DOCUMENTS permission was introduced in Android 13. Gradle 4.1.3 does not support Android 13, so it will not add the Manifest.permission.WRITE_MEDIA_DOCUMENTS permission to your AndroidManifest.xml file automatically.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe you are being affected by this bug of android [Camera bug](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=1480).

The workaround to which is proposed here [Work around](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1932268/1089811).

I hope it helps..

Comment: I know its very late but your answer and work around is not related to the question because this is the case of custom camera and there are no intent involved in this.

Answer (score 10):

Also refer this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7119164/show-my-layout-while-surfaceview-is-loading-camera-preview)

You are calling the last three lines too early. You have to wait for the surface to be prepared before calling setPreviewDisplay() and you have to wait for the surface to be sized (surfaceChanged()) before calling startPreview(). [This project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/tree/master/Camera/Preview/) has what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Bit of an odd issue I've just found relating to black camera preview.
In my case it turned out to be because I had the manifest options

> PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK  and also 
>   REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES"/>
```

Why these affect the camera like this I don't know - or whether it's just related to the device I'm using - but removing these permissions resolved my issue.  It's taken me 2 hours of stripping a project down to figure out where the issue came in!