# Whole screen goes black on my first call to the android Camera

Tags: android, camera

The first time I call for the camera using this code,

```
    mCamera = getCameraInstance();  // Create an instance of Camera
    // Create our Preview view and set it as the content of our activity.
    mPreview = new CameraPreview(this, mCamera);// Create our Preview view and set it as the content of our activity.
    FrameLayout preview = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.quest_image);
    preview.addView(mPreview);
```

the entire screen goes dark for a moment and then the preview screen shows the preview.  All other calls have just the preview screen flash black and then shows preview. How I have just the preview screen flash black even on the first call?  Thanks

Comment: Please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8641736/android-camera-preview-still-black

Comment: I am fine with the preview going black for a half second.  I want to avoid the initial full screen going black for a half second.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SurfaceView flashes black on load](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8772862/surfaceview-flashes-black-on-load)