# AsyncTask Open Camera

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, android-asynctask, android-camera

I've an activity that uses full screen `SurfaceHolder`, opening camera for preview (based on `zxing` code).

Starting this activity results slow (1.x second), I think because of the heavy lifting of the camera manager. I'm using `onResume` method; is it a good idea to move the code inside an `AsyncTask`?

I'd like to immediately render the layout and then wait for the camera (i think it's a better user experience). How can i handle this?

Activity

```
private class CameraTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    SurfaceHolder.Callback callback;

    public CameraTask(SurfaceHolder.Callback callback) {
        this.callback = callback;
    }
    protected void doInBackground() {
        cameraManager = new CameraManager(getApplication());
        viewfinderView = (ViewFinderView) findViewById(R.id.viewfinder_view);
        viewfinderView.setCameraManager(cameraManager);
        SurfaceView surfaceView = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.preview_view);
        SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder = surfaceView.getHolder();

        if (hasSurface) {
            initCamera(surfaceHolder);
        } else {
            surfaceHolder.addCallback(callback);
        }
    }
}
```

This code has no errors, but layout rendering still wait for camera opening.
I'm calling execute method of `AsyncTask` in `onResume`, is it the correct location?

Comment: does the camera have its necessary permission on AndroidManifest already?

Comment: Please post the code in your onResume() method and also any related methods like initCamera()

Comment: To find out what it's waiting on, you should place log messages everywhere. This will allow you to see where the delay is and from there you can find out why.

Comment: Manifest is ok, onResume calls task execute (and nothing else), initCamera simply open (method) Camera.

Comment: Opening the camera may holds the UI Thread for an extended period of time on some devices.

Comment: I know that, I just want to show the layout as a placeholder for the user, waiting the time necessary to the camera.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution found here: [Show my Layout while SurfaceView is loading Camera Preview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7119164/show-my-layout-while-surfaceview-is-loading-camera-preview). Basically, add SurfaceView programatically and not inside your xml layout.

Answer (score 1):

Here's your answer (caution part):

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html#open%28int%29

Note that it is not as simple as it may seems and as suggested in other answers since the `AsyncTask` may not run immediately. So consider this: you start the `AsyncTask`, then the context is switched to the main thread that calls `onPause()`, thus not calling release since the reference to the camera is null. But now the `AsyncThread` starts executing again opening the camera. Now you have a paused `Activity` that still holds an open `Camera` object.
Everything that doesn't involve:

- joining the AsyncTask as some point
- or using some synchronization method
- or running operations on camera sequentially

may lead to race conditions, errors (like when calling camera methods on a not-opened camera) and resource leakage.